# How to mock in pytest global variable in imported module

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module with methods, that I want to test with pytest. In my module I set up global vars such as CONFIG and SESSION etc. to use them in various places.

**my_common_module.py**, located in /my_project/my_common_module.py

```
import yaml
import os
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def get_data(url):
    response = SESSION.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        assets = response.json()
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f'ERROR during request: {url}')
    return assets


def read_config(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as yaml_file:
    return yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)


CONFIG = read_config(os.sys.argv[1])
SESSION = requests.Session()
SESSION.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(os.environ['USER'], os.environ['PASS'])
```

**Run command:**

```
python my_common_module.py config.yaml
```

**test_my_common_module.py** located in /my_project/tests/test_my_common_module.py

```
from my_common_module import read_config, SESSION
import pytest

def test_get_data_success(monkeypatch):

    class MockResponse(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.status_code = 200

        @staticmethod
        def json(self):
            return {'name': 'value'}

    def mock_get():
        return MockResponse()

    url = 'https://testurl.com'
    monkeypatch.setattr(SESSION, 'get', mock_get)
    assert get_all_assets(url) == {'name': 'value'}
```

When I run:

```
pytest tests
```

I got this error:

```
tests/test_my_common_module.py:1: in <module>
from my_common_module import get_data, SESSION
my_common_module.py:20: in <module>
CONFIG = read_config(os.sys.argv[1])
my_common_module:16: in read_config
with open(path, 'r') as yaml_file:
E   IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'tests'

==========================short test summary info ==================================
ERROR tests/test_my_common_module.py - IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'tests'
```

How can I mock or patch CONFIG os.sys.argv[1] or the whole method read_config, before I imported **my_commons_module** in **test_my_common_module.py** and avoid this error?

Comment: You can't. Whatever is written on the top-level in a module is executed on import. Mocking happens afterwards. What you could do is mock `sys.argv`.

Comment: you'll also have to mock `read_config`

Comment: @L3viathan, at what step I could mock sys.argv? With unittest I could patch it in __init__ but in pytest I could find a way how to do it

Comment: Before you do the importing of your module. Just move the import into the actual test.